# Set MPVolumeView slider thumb position as device volume

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, mpvolumeview

I use [MPVolumeView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPVolumeView_Class/) to generate a horizontal slider which allows me to manage the volume of the audio being played. It works great. However, at initialization, I want the slider **takes the position corresponding to volume of the device and not 0.5**, the default:

[image]
[image]

Here is the code I have done:

```
func volumeSlider() {

    let parentVolumeView = MPVolumeView(frame: volumeParentView.bounds)

    for view in parentVolumeView.subviews {
        if (view as UIView).description.rangeOfString("MPVolumeSlider") != nil {
            mpVolumeSlider = view as! UISlider
            print("mpVolumeSlider.value : ", mpVolumeSlider.value)

            // Tried to set mpVolumeSlider.value to volume device, but didn't work, show : 0.0
            // mpVolumeSlider.value = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().outputVolume
        }
        // Remove device volume indicator
        self.view!.addSubview(parentVolumeView)
    }

    let thumbImage = UIImage(named: "slider-image")
    slider?.setThumbImage(thumbImage, forState: .Normal)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign your slider's `value` to to `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().outputVolume` on `init` or in `viewDidLoad` of your view controller.  Remember to `import AVFoundation` to use `AVAudioSession`.

Alternatively, you can programmatically initialize your `MPVolumeView` instead of having it as an outlet.  I believe that is the source of your issue.

Comment: @Zl3n What doesn't work?  Does the `outputVolume` not match the current device's volume?

Comment: When I do `mpVolumeSlider ?.setValue(0.1, animated: true)`, into the function or into `init()`, this doesn't do anything ... However device volume keep modified.

Comment: You're not using `outputVolume`.  Did you try `mpVolumeSlider?.setValue(AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().outputVolume, animated: true)` on `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: @Zl3n is there a requirement to use Interface Builder?  `MPVolumeView` should adjust to the system volume automatically.  What happens if you programmatically initialize your `MPVolumeView` instead of having it as an outlet?